# Directly connecting two NAS boxes

Tags: networking, router, nas, redundancy

I have two NAS units: a Synology and a QNAP. They are both connected to my router via a switch, but since both have spare Ethernet sockets, I guessed that they could also be connected directly, offering independence from the router and perhaps some speed improvement

I connected two sockets using a 2m length of Cat 6a straight-through cable. The LEDs at both ends lit and flashed correctly

But rather than enhancing the network as I had intended, I am now unable to connect to the router and one of my NAS units from a browser

I realise that my expectation may have been simplistic, but I don't know what to do now to fix the network. I will try giving IP addresses to the two new connectors, but otherwise I can't think what may help, beyond removing the new connector

Can someone please suggest something more intelligent?

Comment: The question is...what are you hoping to achieve by connecting them together?  "Independence of the router" is an odd concept given that routers are actually 4-in-1s that are routers, firewalls, switches, and WAPs.  Which part do you want to make it independent of?  Secondly, how are you going to increase performance if it's independent of the router meaning how would other nodes access it?

Comment: I am imagining a weekly backup from one unit to the other. It could be started on Friday night, leaving all other equipment powered off until Monday. Regarding the increase in performance, I hoped that a simple copper wire would have an advantage over a router path because of minimal overhead. Feel free to disabuse me of these notions if you will.

Comment: Assuming that both NAS' are connected to the same switch and both are GBit switches, you're not going to get an increase in performance; it's the same speed.

Comment: @Allan: Perhaps;I was afraid of that. Can you explain why the configuration that I have isn't working, and suggest sonething that would fare better?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that it sounds like you didn't assign IPs to the two network ports you want to directly connect.  It will perform the backup as you describe, there just won't be any benefit.

Comment: @Allan: Okay I'll try that tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Does it support lagg? Or port aggregation? (The switch it's connected to will also have to support it.) But locally you can get better speeds, i.e more people connecting to it simultaneously if both support it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have created a switching loop and need to look into the spanning tree algorithm to fix it or just get rid of the connection between the 2 units you have made.

https://www.dummies.com/programming/networking/cisco/effect-of-a-network-loop/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol

I am unsure how those nas units operate but for Windows OS styles you can do a backup over the network so what I would do is throw all my files onto one NAS then have that NAS make a redundant backup to the other. This way I always have a redundant backup for my stuff. As for connecting the two I am not sure what the best way to do this is.